# What is faster? Refresh the whole table with constant freq. or refresh necessary rows with same freq

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a table with N rows.

The table is attached to WebSocket. Let it be a quotes table.

There are two ways.

1) Update the whole table when any quote received, but limit updates to 1 per second.

2) Update only the row that represent the quote, but limit the frequency to 1 per second for any particular row.

In first case I have fixed amount of redraws per second. But each redraw takes more time while table grows.

In second case I have fixed time per redraw of a single row. But the amount of redraws grow when the table grows.

What is better?

Important to say, that I use a cluster of DIVs instead of table element to represent the data. I'm not sure may it also affect the result or not.

Comment: It really depends on how big the table gats and how often rows are changed. If you have a relatively small table with lots of changes then update the whole table. If you have a Hudge table with seldom changes then update per row. It all depends on how your data input behaves

Comment: In both cases the number of redraws grows with the table, but in the first case you have to redraw all the table and in the second case only the chaged rows. Why would the first option be better than the second?

Comment: @Juan: Image the table has 100 Entries and gets 30-50 rows changed per second

Comment: @VictorRadu It still is 50 changes vs 100, only in the worst case you end up redrawing all the table.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a particular row is much faster than redrawing the whole table. Redrawing a small part of the dom is much more efficient than re-drawing the whole thing.

This is why the concept of `Virtual DOM` is a thing (like in react and vue).

> DOM manipulation is the heart of the modern, interactive web. Unfortunately, it is also a lot slower than most JavaScript operations.
>
> As an example, let's say that you have a list that contains ten items. You check off the first item. Most JavaScript frameworks would rebuild the entire list. That's ten times more work than necessary! Only one item changed, but the remaining nine get rebuilt exactly how they were before.
>
> https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom

Using something like react as a framework will abstract these problems from you, so you dont have to worry what you are updating, react will update only what is needed. Doing it manually is also possible but might be tiresome.

**The bottomline is that changing the smallest parts of the dom is better than redrawing the whole thing.**

Comment: Those are good points, but I'd like to point out that the used resources from the network (web socket data transfer) and even the database where the table data is coming from might be even more crucial to optimize. When talking about many data base queries compared to one, in this case it also depends on how the data is updated and how often (manually by a user, or maybe by an automated script modifying multiple rows or the whole table at once).

Comment: @xander couldnt agree more. its always a good idea to run the profiler before optimizing things as well.